# Multiple conditions in CSS-Selector returning empty value

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to the select the content of a meta tag where a specific language is set like this:

```
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="en" content="Subject 1 english">
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="en" content="Subject 2 english">
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="fr" content="Subject 1 french">
<meta name="DC.Subject" xml:lang="fr" content="Subject 2 french">
```

If I use the following css-selector, I am able to extract only meta tags in English:

```
response.css('meta[xml\:lang="en"]::attr(content)')
```

However, since the website has other meta tags like `<meta name="DC.Description" xml:lang="en" content="Description English">` and `<meta name="DC.Description" xml:lang="fr" content="Description French">`, **I need a second condition in order to separate description from subject**.

Usually it would work like this:

```
response.css('meta[name="DC.Subject"] [xml\:lang="en"]::attr(content)')
```

But unfortunately **this will return an empty value**. I have no idea why multiple conditions don't work in this case. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried removing the empty space between the two attribute selectors?

Comment: Oh, man. I honestly thought I did try that, but obviously I had some other mistake in my code than. Removing the empty space indeed works perfectly. Thank you so much!